# Should I use two components for edit and create form in angular?

Tags: angular

I made a create form which makes post data to the database. Now I need to make an update form.  Do I need to create a separate component  for update form?  Or should I use the same component for both update and create form?

here is my template code,

```
template: `
    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="this.createExperience()" [formGroup]="this.formGroup">
         <div formArrayName="dayanddescriptions">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let dayAndDescription of this.formGroup.controls.dayanddescriptions.controls; let i = index" >           
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <span>Day {{i + 1}}</span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="i>0"  
                                (click)="removeDayandDescription(i)">                    
                                </span>
                            </div>          
                            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
                            <!--Day-->
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-4" >
                                    <label for="text">Day</label>
                                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="day" [ngModel]="i + 1"  readonly>                    
                                </div>
                            <!--Description-->
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                                    <label>Description</label>
                                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description">
                                </div>                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </form>
   <div class="margin-20">
        <a (click)="addDayandDescription()" style="cursor: default">
        Add another day +
        </a>
    </div>
    <pre> form: {{ this.formGroup.value | json }} </pre>
  `,
here is the component,
ngOnInit() {   
      this.createForm();
  } 
  public buildForm(buildFormObject) {        
     this.formGroup = buildFormObject;        
  }
   initDayandDescription() {       
      return this._formBuilder.group({
          day: ['', Validators.required],
          description: [''],
      });
  }   
   addDayandDescription() {
      const control: FormArray = this.formGroup.get('dayanddescriptions') as FormArray;
      control.push(this.initDayandDescription());
  }
  createForm() {
      this.buildForm(this._formBuilder.group({

          dayanddescriptions: this._formBuilder.array([
              this.initDayandDescription(),
          ]),           
          hashtags: '',           
      }));
  }
```

Comment: There could be a whole bunch of arguments in favor of both options. It is impossible to make a sensible decision from what you told. The question is too broad and undetermined.

Comment: i suggest you to create two components for updating and creating the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could create one common form component, that accept @Input is a FormGroup, then create Edit and Create form, setup form (edit form will have values), passing your form to common form component:

**Common**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tpc-cm-form',
  template: `
   <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input formControlName="example" type="text"> <br>
    <textarea formControlName="sectionContent"></textarea>
   </div>
  `
})
export class CMForm {
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
}
```

**Create**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tpc-cr-form',
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="form">
    <tpc-cm-form [formGroup]="form"></tpc-cm-form>
   </form>
  `
})
export class CreateForm {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      example: '',
      sectionContent: ''
    });
  }
}
```

**Edit**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tpc-ed-form',
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="form">
    <tpc-cm-form [formGroup]="form"></tpc-cm-form>
   </form>
  `
})
export class EditForm {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      example: '',
      sectionContent: ''
    });

    // fetch data from API for example
    this.form.patchValue({
      example: 'Simple data',
      sectionContent: 'Content textarea'
    });
  }
}
```

online demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/NWgzGdUc9cDkKujPgrl4?p=preview

Comment: sorry your answer did not solve my problem.
i have form like like below, how can i separate it with create and edit component?
http://plnkr.co/edit/Gs02hMFBhi4SAu19WZoQ?p=preview

Comment: hey, what am I show to you, it just demo, you need apply to your own scenario, just grab all content inside `<form></form>`, move to new component, DIY.

Comment: i tried working with your concept of separation, that is suited for simple form, i have a nested form group, how can it work?
Please have look at this code in plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/Gs02hMFBhi4SAu19WZoQ?p=preview

Comment: It'll work, you can put your `this.formGroup` to common component, then just add formGroupName bound before bind formArrayName.

Comment: where can i place the nested formgroups and call a method that adds day and description? is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: put it all to your component form, such as this thing: `addDayandDescription`

Comment: I thought it should work but felt very difficult to use this way of separation of code. for example if i place the formgroups, including the nested formgroups in the common form, where can i place this method?
<div class="margin-20">
        <a (click)="addDayandDescription()" style="cursor: default">
        Add another day +
        </a>
    </div>

Comment: This approach is dirty, I will surely go with separating Edit and Create component. That way, it will be much easier for anyone to inherit the code and understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a common form component for both.if the router path of form is say
 **/createform** (no parameter) then open form for create mode.Also for edit case we will open that componet with a router param (ex-**/createform/edit**) and with help of router param you can update the form in edit mode.

to get router param

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params.get('paramName'));

    });
```

i have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-parameters-qs3h1u) for you